# Need Help for Android Doze Mode

Tags: android

How to detect app in doze mode . I used PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED receiver but it doesn't help. I use web socket so i don't want to use GCM . Please help.

How to detect when the system goes into doze mode and if there is a 10 Sec gap for fetching notification how to activate it for my App. basically need help for a proper app synchronization without using GCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the user to whitelist the app from power save, use GCM, or get your app pre-installed so it can be white listed by the OEM.  Those are about your only options.

Comment: thank you but @Gabe as per my info for that i have to navigate user to setting screen manually but i want to avoid that.

Comment: Then there is no way to do it. Those 3 ways above are the only ways. Gcm, whitelisting by user, or whitelisting by oem.

Comment: is there any way to get broadcast or something when device move to doze mode ?

Comment: No. The entire point of size is to stop processing and battery usage. Broadcasting that its going to happen would be counter to the point